# how to use highcharts.js in magento frontend?

Tags: magento2, javascript, 3rd-party-library

I have followed require js config to include highchats.js in the cms page

`app/design/frontend/Namesapce/Theme/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js`
**Code**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'owl':'Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel.min',
            'highchart':'Magento_Theme/js/highcharts'

    },
    shim: {
        'owl': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'highchart': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Highchart function is called in **.phtml** file

`app/design/frontend/Namesapce/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/highchart.phtml`

And **Script**

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "highchart"
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function($){
        $(".learn-btn").click(function(){

            $(function(){
                $('#container').highcharts(
                {chart:{type:'bar'},colors:['#de0202','#ffa903','#19d800'],title:{text:'Results'},xAxis:{categories:['50% Probability','20% Probability','5% Probability','1% Probability']},yAxis:{min:0,title:{text:'Maximum Number of Weeks to Resolve'}},legend:{reversed:true},plotOptions:{series:{stacking:'normal'}},credits:{enabled:false},series:[{name:'Weeks in  May End',data:[c50F,c80F,c95F,c99F]},{name:'Weeks Your ',data:[Weeks,Weeks,Weeks,Weeks]},{name:'Weeks ',data:[age,age,age,age]}]}
                );
            });


          });
        });
    });
```

**Even tried this**

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "highchart"
    ], function ($,highchart) {
        $(document).ready(function($){
        $(".learn-btn").click(function(){

            var myChart = highchart.chart('container', {
           {
            chart:{type:'bar'},
            colors:['#de0202','#ffa903','#19d800'],
            title:{text:'Results'},
            xAxis:{categories:['50% Probability','20% Probability','5% Probability','1% Probability']},
            yAxis:{min:0,title:{text:'Maximum Number of Weeks to Resolve'}},
            legend:{reversed:true},
            plotOptions:{series:{stacking:'normal'}},
            credits:{enabled:false},
            series:[{name:'Weeks',
                data:[c50F,c80F,c95F,c99F]},
                {name:'Weeks',
                data:[Weeks,Weeks,Weeks,Weeks]},
                {name:'Weeks ',data:[age,age,age,age]}
            ]}

        });


          });
        });
    });
```

**Still getting this error TypeError: highcharts is undefined  and TypeError: highchart is undefined for the 2nd way**

Comment: did you solved the problem ? @amit-bera, got same problem with chartist, chart js and apexchart.. don't understand why charts doestn't works

Comment: yes, it is fixed for me. I do not remember how i did. I will check my code and let you know

Answer (score 0):

First i added  hightchats js using below code:

```
<script>
    require.config({
        packages: [{
            name: 'highcharts',
            main: 'highcharts'
        }],
        paths: {
            // Change this to your server if you do not wish to use our CDN.
            'highcharts': 'https://code.highcharts.com'
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Then I access below way:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'highcharts',
        'highcharts/modules/exporting',
        'highcharts/modules/accessibility'
    ], function($,ui,Highcharts) {

        ......

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery',
        'highcharts',
        'highcharts/modules/exporting',
        'highcharts/modules/accessibility'
    ], function ($, Highcharts) {

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    overflow:'allow',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        wordBreak: 'break-all'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                visible : true,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '$' + this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>${point.y:.1f}</b>'
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Population',
                data: [
                    ['5 Year Savings', 0],
                    ['10 Year Savings', 0],
                    ['15 Year Savings', 0]
                ],
                color: '#1E65D8',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#54C663',
                    align: 'center',
                    format: '${point.y}', // one decimal
                    y: 4, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '11px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });


        // Build the chart
        // Build the chart
        Highcharts.chart('piechart', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    fontSize:'9px',
                    font: '9pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
                },
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>$ {point.y}</b>'
            },
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                }
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        format: '${point.y}',
                        enabled: true,
                        distance: -170,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color:'black'
                        }
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Cost',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'Current Annual AC Cost',
                    color: '#1E65D8'
                }, {
                    name: 'New Annual AC Cost',
                    color: '#3BAD4A'
                }]
            }]
        });
    });

</script>
```